# Crystal Reports rounding number

Tags: crystal-reports, rounding, number-formatting

In Crystal Report my field values are like:

```
1
12
2.5
```

If I format the decimal as 1.00 and round as 0.01 the output is:

```
1.00
12.00
2.50
```

But I want to display

```
 1.00 as 1 
 2.50 as 2.50
```

How to display in actual number format?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field e.g. `ff_act_val` and set its value as:

```
if Int({table_name.field_name}) = {table_name.field_name} then
    ToText({table_name.field_name}, 0)
else
    ToText({table_name.field_name}, 2)
```

Replace `table_name.field_name` with formula field `ff_act_val` in the designer. Do **NOT** format this formula field.